# Odoo Module Creation - KeyError: '#id'

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I used Python to construct an Odoo module, but I am unable to launch it locally due to unknown issues. Despite having a good work structure, I keep running into these unknown errors: launch errors.

Does any one know how to fix this?

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\http.py", line 1722, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\service\model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\http.py", line 1749, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\http.py", line 1953, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 222, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\http.py", line 722, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "e:\appodoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 28, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "e:\appodoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 20, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\api.py", line 468, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\api.py", line 453, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-77>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 75, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 467, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(self.env.registry[self._name].button_install)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 591, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-16>", line 2, in new
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 113, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 480, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(env, graph,
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 364, in load_marked_modules`your text`
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 227, in load_module_graph
    load_data(env, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 71, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(env, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 623, in convert_file
    convert_csv_import(env, module, pathname, fp.read(), idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 665, in convert_csv_import
    result = env[model].with_context(**context).load(fields, datas)
  File "E:\AppOdoo\odoo\models.py", line 1184, in load
    if isinstance(model_fields[field_path[0]], odoo.fields.Many2one):
KeyError: '#id'

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    RPCError@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/2df272c/web.assets_web.min.js:2871:319
    makeErrorFromResponse@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/2df272c/web.assets_web.min.js:2874:163
    jsonrpc/promise</<@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/2df272c/web.assets_web.min.js:2878:34
```

Comment: Why is there a pound in front of 'id'? KeyError: '#id'

Comment: Please provide  a [mcve].

Comment: You have a .csv file in your module. Can you provide atleast the first 2 lines of that file?